# How to verify only a part of JSON Response value in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, assertion

Response JSON contains field as:
"scheduledTimestamp":"2017-07-23T18:02:37.000Z"

What I need to do is to assert something like:

```
Verify $.data.scheduledTimestamp contains "2017-07-23T18:02:37"
```

(ignore the milliseconds value)

I tried Response Assertion as:

```
Text Response - checked
Contains - checked
Pattern To Test -  "scheduledTimestamp":"${con_res_date}(.+?)"
```

where `con_res_date` = `2017-07-23T18:02:37`

But the assertion still failed.

Comment: Did you tried scheduledTimestamp":"${con_res_date}?

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps):

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> - a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
> - a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

So you need to amend your [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configuration as follows:

- Pattern Matching Rules: `Substring`
- Patterns to Test: `scheduledTimestamp":"${con_res_date}`

Comment: I need to verify that schedule timestamp is this along with ignoring the milliseconds value within them

Comment: I have done this by below mentioned steps:

1. Add a JSR223 Assertion instead of Response Assertion
2. In JSR223 Assertion, provided these line of codes
'import groovy.json.*;

def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();    
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response);

assert json.data.scheduledTimestamp.startsWith("${con_res_date}")'

Comment: Never inline JMeter variables into groovy scripts as it may cause compilation errors. Moreover, it ruins Groovy script [compilation cache](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/compile-groovyscript-at-runtime-allow-caching-of-compiled-source-to-avoid-recompilation-at-runtime-using-groovyclassloader/) feature. Also `assert` keyword won't fail your Sampler, you need to use something like: `if (!json.data.scheduledTimestamp.startsWith(vars.get('con_res_date')) { AssertionResult.setFailure(true)}`. See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more information.